# Reverse foreign key - bug in Django?

Tags: python, django

We are using Django 1.4.13 with foreign keys - we have class BusinessUnit which inherits from a class with a foreign key to class ContentSet. We have the following function in class ContentSet:

```
def business_units_default_content_set_count(self):
    """
    Returns the number of business units linked to this content set as default.
    """
    return len(set([bu.pk for bu in list(self.businessunit_set.all())]))
```

The problem is that if we create a ContentSet without a primary key (we don't save it to disk), this function returns an integer which is not 0 (for example 30). I solved this problem by changing the function to:

```
def business_units_default_content_set_count(self):
    """
    Returns the number of business units linked to this content set as default.
    """
    if (self.pk):
        return len(set([bu.pk for bu in list(self.businessunit_set.all())]))
    else:
        return 0
```

But why do we have to check `self.pk` at all? Is it a bug of Django 1.4.13? And if it is, is it fixed in other versions of Django?

Comment: That whole function could be reduced to `return self.businessunit_set.all().count()` (since it is impossible to have duplicate entries in a queryset).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I agree. We have another function returning `len(set([bu.pk for bu in list(self.business_units.all()) + list(self.businessunit_set.all())]))` and this function is a copy of the other function without `list(self.business_units.all())`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to fetch all businessunit using the reverse relation django is connecting to database, filtering all the child objects by its parent.

Maybe the problem is because you have some BusinessUnits that aren't linked to any ContentSet

Comment: Yes, I think we have business units which are not linked to any content set. But they should not appear as related to a content set without a primary key.

Comment: When you have a BusinessUnit instace not beign saved, its pk/id is None/null, so if you filter: Child.objects.filter(parent=parent_obj) is the same as Child.objects.filter(parent_id=None) or in SQL parent_id = null... so, obviously you will get all childs objects without a parent.

What you can do to not list this childs is to add .exclude(parent=None) after .all()... beign parent the ForeignKey attribute of the child

Comment: I think it's a bug in Django because `self.businessunit_set.all()` should be empty if self.pk is None.